# RestKit Object Mapping: How to map from key values to new object / relation?

Tags: ios, json, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

Not sure if the title describes the problem the best, if you have better description please edit the title.

So I am implementing an app that deals with product orders. In each order, there are "line items", namely order information for each product. The JSON data of the "line item" we got from the REST API call looks like this:

JSON data:

```
"line_item":{
   "id":1234, // Product ID
   "name":"Cliff Bar",
   "sold_price":12.00,
   "sold_quantity":25
}
```

CoreData Object (in JSON format):

```
"line_item"{
   "product":{
     "id":1234,
     "name":"Cliff Bar",
     "description":"Awesome food",
     "inventory_level":12,
     "standard_price":11.00
   },
    "sold_price":12.00,
    "sold_quantity":25
}
```

As you can see, "id" and "name" are more like the "identifier" of the product sold, "primary key" if you will. (CoreData doesn't have the notion of primary key, RestKit kind of does) When I get JSON info from the rest API, it actually "collapsed" the product object inside of the line_item object for performance concerns.

Question 1: How should I deal with this?

Do I create new product object with key values other than "id" and "name" null if the product does not exist? And then I will fetch full product object if it is needed. Is it a good approach?

If I do not create these incomplete object and just keep the CoreData object defined the same as the JSON object. I'm afraid there isn't a strong relation between objects in CoreData.

Suggest a better solution if you have one!

Question 2:

If the answer is yes to question 1, how do I map 2 key values ("name" and "id") to fields of one newly created object ("id" and "name" of "product" inside of "line_item")? I haven't found any information about this in any tutorial.

Love to hear how you would approach this problem. Thanks!

Comment: What core data model do you want to map to. Design that then look at how to construct the mapping. Don't design the mapping and then create the model from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand your question. But with your json, if I were you, I would create my Core Data like this:

1. Line_item:

   - attribute:

     - sold_price
     - sold_quantity
   - relationship:

     - product
2. Product

   - attribute:

     - id
     - name
     - description
     - inventory_level
     - standard_price
   - relationship:

     - items

And then I create RestKit mapping depend on this.

```
RKManagedObjectStore *mos = [RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore;
RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Line_item" inManagedObjectStore:mos];
mapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"id"];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"sold_quantity", @"sold_price"]];

[mapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"product" mapping:[Product manageObjectMappingDefinition]];
```

Oh, I realize my code and struct is not compatible with your json.

Here is the question, how you identify your line_item? Without it, I can't set the `identificationAttributes`.

Comment: Product is identified by product id. Line item don't really have one.. Can this be a problem?

Comment: @Sullivan I think it depends on the relationship between line item and product. If your product may have several line items, that would be a problem. According to the RestKit `RKEntityMapping` Document, `identificationAttributes ` are used during mapping to determine whether an existing object should be updated or a new managed object should be inserted

Comment: @Putting Wong  There is nothing in JSON I can use as identification attribute. It's probably OK if I just keep the relationships clear since I'm not going to update line_item.

Comment: @Putting Wong Do I need to create 2 mappings for both JSON=>MO and MO=>JSON?

Comment: @Sullivan In my project, I create 2 mappings, because the response and request is different. Checkout `RKObjectManager` and [Object Mapping - RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping)

Comment: But when I define 2 mappings, the console says that the mapping is duplicated. Do I have to combine 2 mapping dictionaries into 1?